# How to specify path to user.properties file when jmeter starts

Tags: jmeter-5.0

My `jmeter` is in director `d1` and I want to use a `user.properties` file which is in directory `d2`. I can't see option in `jmeter` cli to provide path to a `user.properties` file (except for `-S --systemPropertyFile <argument>` which I am not sure would work or not.

Does the `user.properties` file need to be in same directory as `jemeter`'s?

Answer (score 0):

Use **-p property-file** option. For example:

```
jmeter -n -t example.jmx -p ~/d1/user.properties
```

See the following [article](https://octoperf.com/blog/2019/01/14/flexible-test-plans/) for a detailed explanation and more examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can place in any other location.

Invoking JMeter as "jmeter -?" will print a list of all the command-line options.
user.properties file does not have to be in the bin directory.
Also you could see [1.4.8 Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html) in official website.

```
    -p, --propfile <argument>
        the jmeter property file to use
    -q, --addprop <argument>
        additional JMeter property file(s)
```

Use **-q** option for user.properties.Option **-p** is for jmeter.properties